# Если аргумент функции указатель или ссылка, обязаятельно ли возвращать ее из функции

Tags: c++

В функцию можно отправить:
- аргумент
- ссылку на аргумент
- указатель на аргумент (на адрес значения переменной)

Теперь о факте пользы возвратного значения..
Например, нужно через функцию изменить значение переменной
- если отправляю аргумент в функцию, то необходимо получить обратно, это понятно

Далее обязательно получать измененное значение из функции, если я передал в нее ссылку на переменную или указатель?
Ведь таким способом оно и так же изменится по ссылке или указателю?

Конечная версия использования указателей в функции

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    //
    // определения функций (!)
    //
    int mul(int );  // с обычным аргументом
    void div(int &); // с сылкой на аргумент
    void sqr(int *); // с указателем на аргумент

    int main(void)
    {
        int a = 6;
        mul(a); /* передача аргумента (копии) */
        cout<<"6 * 2 = "<<a<<endl;
        a = 6;
        div(a);  /* передача аргумента (функция принемает ссылку на аргумент) */
        cout<<"6 * 2 = "<<a<<endl;
        a = 6;
        sqr(&a);  /*  передача указателя с адресом на значение аргумента */
        cout<<"6 * 6 = "<<a<<endl;
        system("pause");
     return 0;
    }

    //
    // Ф У Н К Ц И И (!)
    //
    int mul(int b){ /*прием аргумента A*/ 
        b *= 2;
        return b; /*для конечного изменения значения, необходимо  вернуть аргумент*/ 
    }
    void div(int &b){ /*прием ссылки на аргумент A*/ 
        b /= 2;
    /*для конечного изменения значения, возвращать аргумент не требуется*/ 
    }
    void sqr(int *b){ /*прием указателя с адресом на значение аргумента A*/ 
        *b *= *b;
    /*для конечного изменения значения, возвращать аргумент не требуется*/ 
    }
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода, что вы пытаетесь сделать, а то по текущей формулировке вопроса нормально ответить можно лишь копипастой целой главы учебника.

Comment: Нет. Функция принимает только аргумент. Типом аргумента может быть, например, `int`, `int&`, `int*` и ещё бесконечно много других вариантов.

Comment: обновил описание

Comment: эту заготовку я сделал как памятку, если не трудно поправьте мои ошибки пж

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас немного неправильное понятие об аргументах. Указатель является частью типа переменной, ссылка - указывает, что мы задаем ещё одно имя для одной и той же переменной (одна и та же область памяти). Функция может принимать значение, либо ссылку как аргумент, указатель является вполне конкретным значением. Теперь рассмотрим что же происходит в трех ваших вариантах передачи аргумента.

Первый вариант - `int mul(int );` - передача аргумента по значению. Когда мы вызываем функцию, то у нас существует наша переменная `a`, при передаче в функцию будет создана копия этой переменной, и все действия в ней будут выполнятся над копией, в результате чего исходное значение не изменится.

Второй вариант - `int div(int &);` - передача аргумента по ссылке. Когда мы вызываем функцию, то у нас существует наша переменная `a`, в функцию будет передаваться она же, т. е. если мы в процессе выполнения функции будет её менять, то поменяется и исходное значение.

Третий вариант - `int sqr(int *);` - Это та же самая передача аргумента по значению (как и в варианте 1), только в этот раз мы выделяем память на хранение указателя, записываем туда адрес нашей переменной `a`, и именно этот адрес передаётся. Над самой переменной `a` мы в данном случае ничего не делаем, пока мы по указателю к ней не обратимся.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!   Это вроде понятно, но все таки, вопрос в том, что в первом варианте для изменения значения переменной ЕЕ необходимо ВЕРНУТЬ из функции так?   Во втором варианте для изменения значения переменной ее ТОЖЕ надо вернуть из функции? А в третьем варианте ее НЕ надо возвращать? она и так изменится же по указателю?

Comment: В третьем случае `a` поменяется при изменении её в функции. В первом - вы можете написать `a = mul(a);`, и только если функция возвращает результат, иначе вытянуть что с копией сделала функция нет абсолютно никакой возможности. Во втором и третьем случае значение можно не возвращать.

Comment: СПС!! Просто преблагодарен за объяснение такой "мелочи", теперь с этим твердо закрепил)     Единственно с типом чар еще будет вопрос, но позже как подготовлю его :)

Comment: **@Yuriy Orlov**, обновил код, теперь, я надеюсь, он правильный =)    заметил интересный баг, если ставлю комментарий так "//"  , то код вобще отрубается и не работает, а если так "/**/"  , то норм.  Наверно там весь код каким-то образом комментируется, очень странно..  ну лан мелочь.    еще такой момент: перезапись переменных в C++ не страшна? в смысле если сделать так **a = mul(a)**

Comment: @Антон за давайте новые вопросы как отдельные вопросы на сайте